# 'Documents & Settings' On another Drive?

Tags: windows-7, sync

Ok, this is similar to some other questions on this site, but none of them go this far.

What I would like to do is completely move the 'Documents and Settings' folder to another drive.  The reason for this is that I use my laptop and a few desktops at home and would like to have a seamless profile across all machines.  What I would like to do is have the entire Documents and Settings folder on a networked drive.  That way application-specific settings will be accessible on all machines as well as my data.

What I have now is a script that synchronizes my application data and documents folders between all of the machines based on the modification date of files.  Instead of duplicating the data, I would like them all to view the same files directly.

Sometimes I will be working upstairs, then move downstairs and would like to be working on the same thing I was working on before.

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 1):

The best you could do is have a Windows Domain Controller (or something similar), and roaming profiles. However, if you use your laptop outside of the home, you would have limited access to anything on the computer with this setup. At the very least I believe the laptop would have to manually sync. I personally don't see the problem with your current, presumably working, system.

Comment: Can a Home-based OS (Win 7. Vista, XP) run as a Domain Controller?  Do I need to run a server-class OS to do this?

Comment: It would work if the networked drive is on his laptop.

Comment: And I agree that relocating Documents and Settings on such divergent OSs is asking for trouble. Better duplicated files than none.

Comment: It is asking for trouble; there's no way to use the same folder for both operating systems.

Comment: I actually missed that there were two different versions of Windows. This would only be doable with roaming profiles if it supports both OSes. I don't know if that's possible. As far as home OS being a DC, I know that only Pro and higher of XP have the DC, not the home versions.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. That's what we have at work; the Documents & Settings folder is on a network drive. I can go to any computer and just carry on working.

Why not try to move the folder and see what happens; you can read a bit about how to do it [here](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/moving_documents_and_settings_folder_onto_second_hard_disk.html).

**Edit**: Joshua is right, the link only referred to the My Documents folder. After digging around a bit, I found [a way](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1409/move-your-documents-and-settings-username-profile-off-of-the-c-drive/) to really move the whole Documents & Settings folder; it seems a bit tricky, involving a lot of registry editing, but maybe it will help you.

Comment: FYI the link only mentions how to move the My Documents folder. Moving Documents and Settings is a *lot* more involved, IIRC.

Comment: That second link looks more to what I am looking for. I'll have a look at that

Comment: FYI, I know the method described in the second link works fine in 2000 and XP, but haven't tried in Vista or 7.